# ArcMap crashing in geoprocessing script with AreaSolarRadiation. Does a log file exist?

Tags: arcmap, geoprocessing, log

I am writing a greoprocessing script in python and running it in arcmap 10.  The script works as expected until it gets to an area solar radiation calculation

```
AreaSolarRadiation(input_dem, "", "400", TimeMultipleDays(2011,1,31),7)
```

It seems every other time I try to run the geoprocessing tool in arcmap the application crashes when it gets to that solar radiation calculation.  Sometimes the crash is followed by a prompt to send ESRI an error report.  Sometimes I don't even get that.  The dem I am calculating area solar for is pretty small so I don't believe the calculation is too intensive.  The script never crashed arcmap before I started trying to do the solar calc.

I am thinking if I could see a log file I might have a better idea of whats going on.  Does anyone know if the arcmap application keeps a log file I could view that would shed light on why it crashed?  This is running on windows server 2003.

Comment: Are you catching any exception that it may be throwing? I don't think the ArcPy/arcgisscripting modules use any logging modules to collect this information.  Try using the try:...except clause around the offending line to see what you get.  Update your post with the results. Good luck ;)

Comment: Often wish Python supported something like AML watch files so you could read line by line output to figure where errors are happening. Exceptions tell you what the final problem was but not much about the context that led to it.